# Linking to tag pages in a Roadkill Wiki page

Tags: roadkill-wiki

When creating a new page in Roadkill Wiki, one can link to a regular page this way (using Markdown notation): `[Link to Page](Page1)`, assuming that `Page1` is an existing page.

I want to create a similar link to a "tag listing" page, like 'http://www.example.com/pages/tag/javascript'.

I know I can use the full URL path this way:
`[Tag Listing](http://www.example.com/pages/tag/javascript)`

but what I'm looking is some other way to achieve that, like a sorthand:
`[Tag Listing](tag:javascript)`

or a relative path:
`[Tag Listing](/pages/tag/javascript)`

Does Roadkill have this feature?

Comment: Do you mean in HTML ? Like a normal anchor tag ? Your question is not clear enough to be solved.

Comment: check again to see if it is clear enough now

Comment: @eltoncezar Did you ever get an answer to this?

Comment: @AGB no man... sorry